80s "TV Movie" set in WWII South East England where children are played by adult actors
I am looking for a movie which was made and based in South East England.  It is set in Second World War and is about a bunch of kids (all played by adult actors common to TV at the time) messing around in the fields and woods during the time.
The end has a tragic accident involving a burning barn and one of the children who is somewhat troubled during the story.
Other story lines including some going to look for Jam Jars in the woods...
Any ideas?

Sounds like the 1979 Play for Today episode  Blue Remembered Hills written by Dennis Potter and starring Helen Mirren. From Wiki:

The play concerns a group of seven-year-olds playing in the Forest of Dean one summer afternoon in 1943. It ends abruptly when the character Donald is burned to death partly as a result of the other children's actions. Perhaps the most striking feature of the play is that, although the characters are children, they are played by adult actors.

It's currently available on Youtube in its entirety if you wish to watch it there.

Yes that is it.  This is great...
